# Finding the region for a triple integral

Tags: calculus

So the semester is over and i'm studying for exams, and this is one of the practice questions I came across.

Where is the centroid of the solid bounded above by the plane z = 1 + x + y, below
by the plane z = −2 and on the sides by the planes x = 1, x = 2, y = 1, y = 2?

I'll be able to work out the centroid bit once I find the volume but I amn't sure which is right  here's what i think it is

say [ (a->b) is the integral from a to b. (sorry, don't know how to do the correct symbols)

then   V = [(1->2) [(4->5) [(-2-> 1+x+y) dz dy dx

or is it V = [(1->2) [(1->2) [(-2-> 1+x+y) dz dy dx

or neither??  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Woops!! sorry forgot the give you the link
here it is http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rectangular room whose floor is $z=-2$ and ceiling is slanted plane $z = 1 + x + y$

The volume is 
$$\int_{1}^2 \int_1^2 ((1+x+y) - (-2)) dy dx= \int_{1}^2 \int_1^2 \int_{-2}^{1+x+y}dz dy dx$$

Comment: ahhh,  yes.  thank you

Comment: @Madmarkshero you are welcome, are you familiar with [latex](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)?

Comment: I've seen people use it, but don't know how to myself.

Comment: @Madmarkshero use the link to create your equations and wrap them between dollar signs to create beautiful equation $\$ \LaTeX \$$